# Django sudden error: "AuthMissingParameter at /complete/google-oauth2/", when using GoogleOAuth2 from social-auth-app-django package

Tags: python, django, google-authentication, django-socialauth

I have a running Django application (runs for already 2 years+). I'm using the [social-auth-app-django](https://pypi.org/project/social-auth-app-django/5.0.0/) to manage my users authentication with Google.

Suddenly today i got errors from users that can not get inside my app. I also get the same error on my local and production environment:

[image]

My `settings.py` related params are:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

## Google Credentials
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_AUTH_SECRET')
print("TESTING")
print("SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY:\n", SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY)
print("SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET:\n", SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET)
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://MyAppHost/complete/google-oauth2/'


# Login URL
LOGIN_URL = '/login/google-oauth2/'
# Where user is directed after login/logout
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

I double verified that the SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY and SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET really match what i see in the [google API-credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)

Moreover, i verified that my Authorized redirect URIs configured properly.

When i try to enter the URL presented in the `redirect_uri` (http://localhost:5000/complete/google-oauth2/) i get the error:

```
AuthMissingParameter at /complete/google-oauth2/
Missing needed parameter state
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: AuthMissingParameter
Exception Value:    
Missing needed parameter state
Exception Location: /Volumes/dev/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py in validate_state, line 85
Python Executable:  /Volumes/dev/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.2
```

Comment: It took me while to solve this, even after consulting with google support which did not help. I don't know how and why, but what solved it was just creating a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID in google credentials page (link in the original message). The weird thing is there is no expiration date for credentails and it wasn't mentioned anywhere that i should need to change it \ create new.